# "No match for operator-" error on simple iterator difference

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++14, const-iterator

Here is my code:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    set<int> st;
    st.insert(1);
    int x = st.find(1) - st.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting `error: no match for 'operator-' in 'st.std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::find [with _Key = int, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>](((const int&)((const int*)(&1)))) - st.std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin [with _Key = int, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]()'`.

I am not able to figure out how did iterator difference stopped working all of a sudden! Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because this operation can't be implemented efficiently on a `std::set`, it is not provided. `std::set` provides [(Constant) Bidirectional Iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), that can be moved in either direction, but not jumped arbitrary distances, like the Random Access Iterators provided by `std::vector`. You can see the hierarchy of iterator concepts [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Instead, use the [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) function, but be aware that for this case, this is an `O(n)` operation, having to walk along every step between the two iterators, so be cautious about using this on large `std::set`s, `std::list`s, etc.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) iterators are [BidirectionalIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), not RandomAccessIterators. The former do not define `operator-`. Use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to calculate the difference between the iterators.

```
#include <iterator>
// ...
auto x = std::distance(st.begin(), st.find(1));
```