# how the iterator in c++ could be printed?

Tags: c++, iterator

Suppose, I have declared a vector in `C++` like this:

```
vector<int>numbers = {4,5,3,2,5,42};
```

I can iterate it through the following code:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it!=numbers.end(); it++){
    // code goes here
}
```

Now, I would talk about coding in the block of `for loop`.

I can access and change any value using this iterator. say, I want to increase every value by 10 and the print. So, the code would be:

```
*it+=10;
cout << *it << endl;
```

I can print the address of both iterator and elements that are being iterated.

Address of iterator can be printed by:

```
cout << &it << endl;
```

Address of iterated elements can be printed by:

```
cout << &(*it) << endl;
```

But **why the iterator itself could not printed by doing the following?**

```
cout << it <<endl;
```

At first I thought the convention came from `JAVA` considering the security purpose. But if it is, then why I could print it's address?

However, **Is there any other way to do this? If not, why?**

Comment: It's just because the iterator has no **implicit** conversion to any data type accepted by `operator<<`.  An iterator acts like a pointer, but it is a distinct type.  Just use `cout << &*it` (as you've already noted)

Comment: there does not exist operator <<(ostream&, iterator of your choice)

Comment: @BenVoigt `cout << &*it` and `cout << &(*it)` are same.

Comment: @Creris is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @manetsus: To do what? Print an iterator? First you have to define what it means to print an iterator.

Comment: That depends on what you want to print

Comment: @BenjaminLindley so why it is undefined? sometimes it becomes difficult to debug!

Comment: @Creris I want to print its representation or how it is in memory or something like that. I want to see how it is managed internally. say, by printing addresses of elements of an array you can easily find its memory consumption etc.

Comment: go inspect the source code. You can at most print its address with std::addressof(iterator)

Comment: @Creris But my question is why it is like this? why I can't?

Comment: @manetsus: It's already been explained to you why. In Baum mit Augen's answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: But how could it possible that a more ambiguous thing like `std::distance(numbered.begin(), numbers.begin())` is defined but this is not?

Comment: @manetsus: What is ambiguous about `std::distance(numbered.begin(), numbers.begin())`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Could it give any defined output as it is measuring the distance between two different vectors named `numbered` and `numbers`?

Comment: @manetsus: Oh, I didn't notice those were two different names. Comparing iterators from different containers is undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: So, what was the problem to define them and marked some undefined behavior where the ambiguity comes?

Comment: @manetsus: Sorry, you'll have to rephrase that. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Sorry for my bad English, "So, what is the problem if they define the printing of iterator? they can easily mark some point as undefined behavior, isn't it?"

Comment: @manetsus: The problem is explained in Baum's answer. *"there is no conventional meaning of printing an iterator"*.

Comment: I could actually print value of iterator (concretely of type vector<int>) by doing this:
*(&(*(iterator))).
Can't really explain what is going on there, but maybe somebody will find it useful to quickly debug or something.

Comment: @Creris Another weird issue found from using std::addressof(iterator) is the value print out by this would always be a constant value and would not change over each iteration, even iterator itself is increase. std::cout << std::addressof(iter) << ", " << &(*iter) << ", " << *iter << std::endl;

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there is a way to do it!

You can't print the iterator because **it is not defined to have a value**.
But you can perform arithematic operations on them and that helps you to print the value (<s>**of the iterator**</s>).

Do the following.

```
cout << it - v.begin();
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector> 
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  vector<int> v = {20,3,98,34,20,11,101,201};           
  sort (v.begin(), v.end());                

  vector<int>::iterator low,up;
  low = lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20);          
  up = upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 20);                  

  std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low - v.begin()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "upper_bound at position " << (up - v.begin()) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output of the above code:

```
lower_bound at position 2
upper_bound at position 4
```

**Note**: this is just a way to get things done and no way I have claimed that we can print the iterator.

...

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. What is the complexity of such arithmetics on iterators?

Comment: It does not work for all iterators as in double linked lists: [“No match for operator-” error on simple iterator difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764251/no-match-for-operator-error-on-simple-iterator-difference)

Comment: `std::distance(it, v.begin())` works for e.g. std::map, per Thomas Matthews's comment on another answer here.

Answer (score 4):

There is no predefined output operator for the standard iterators because there is no conventional meaning of printing an iterator. What would you expect such an operation to print? While you seem to expect to see the address of the object the iterator refers to, I find that not clear at all.

There is no universal answer to that, so the committee decided not to add a those operators. (The last half sentence is a guess, I am not part of the committee.)

If you want to print those iterators, I would define a function like `print(Iterator);` (or something like this, whatever fits your needs) that does what you want. I would not add an `operator <<` for iterators for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: The offset or distance from the beginning may be more useful, something like `std::distance(it, numbers.begin())`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Would be reasonable too, but how would an iterator know where its range begins?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I think that might lead to some hard to trace bugs, especially, if you have a container holding integers. I'd much rather have a compiler error.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews why it prints negative numbers? however, it also prints something when two iterators are of different vectors! strange behavior! It would cause ambiguity!

Comment: @BaummitAugen while comparing like `it!=numbers.end()`, it compares two integers or something, right? I expect that integer to be printed. Sometimes, it becomes difficult to debug. They could define such an ambiguous thing like `std::distance(it, numbers.begin())` but did not it? Huh, ridiculous!

Comment: @manetsus "it!=numbers.end(), it compares two integer or something, " Yeah, or something, whatever that something is. For example, what do think an `std::unordered_set::iterator` would look like, and how would you print that?

Comment: @manetsus: I've never had difficulty debugging because I couldn't print an iterator directly to an `ostream`. The debugger knows how to handle standard iterators, and can output all kinds of information from them. Even if I were to resort to `printf/cout` style debugging, I can easily form whatever expression I need to see the result of, whether it's `*it` or `&it` or `&*it` or `distance(it1, it2)`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen that something must be represented to an integer any how, right? I would like to print something (could be an integer) that represent the orientation it keeps data internally. In brief, I want to see the actual scenario whatever it is `std::unordered_set::iterator` or `std::vector::iterator`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Actually, I wanted to be clear about it's internal work. However, is there any relation between `iterator` and `reverse_iterator`? if yes, why `distance(numbers.rbegin(), numbers.begin())` gives compile error? if no, then how it could be no as it is traversing the same vector?

Comment: @manetsus If you have another question, post it as a question and not as a comment to an answer to a different question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Surely, but this question came as a sequence as I could not get the thing properly.

Comment: @manetsus You can include a link to this question in your new question if you feel like the context helps.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: However, what do you mean by "because there is conventional meaning of printing an iterator"? if it is, what is that conventional meaning?

Comment: @manetsus I'm not sure why you're so certain that iterators are represented by something akin to an integer, no matter what. It is not the case. For example, an `std::list` iterator is mainly a pointer, and has no clue how far it is from the beginning or the end. A hashmap iterator refers to a bucket and a position inside this bucket's list, again with no way to know how far it is from the first or last object in the map.

Comment: @Quentin If it could not be represented as an integer anyhow, how could you get `it!=numbers.end()` ? In case of list and something, you can still print it's pointer in the memory, so, why not it's iterator?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Its okay. Your answer is okay, that's why I up-voted, but I could not satisfy myself enough, so I did not accept your answer till now. If any better answer does not come, I would accept yours. Thanks.

Comment: @manetsus iterators overload the `!=` operator, so it isn't a clue that something happens with integers either. Possible implementation for a singly-linked list : an iterator arriving at the end would detect that the "next" node is in fact `nullptr`. It sets a boolean flag `atEnd` to `true`. The `list.end()` methods return an iterator which always has the flag set. Now you can compare the flags in `operator!=` to achieve the usual syntax : if they are both true, we're comparing two past-the-end iterators.

Comment: @Quentin: `true` can easily represented by `1` which is an integer. However, it could be a `-1` also! As in `JAVA`, if you find a substring in a string and the substring does not occur in the string, it returns `-1`. No need to be an straight-forward integer, it can be derived 'anyhow'.

Comment: @manetsus but printing that boolean (or integer, if you like integers) is not really useful : you can only know whether you're past the end, or not. It's the only information the iterator needs, so it contains nothing else. What you want to print to get a sense of what is going on is just *not there*.

Comment: @Quentin: Sure, but on the other case, I could easily calculate how far I am from the beginning or end! (as mentioned in case of `JAVA` scenario).

Comment: @manetsus not without traversing the whole list again to find your iterator, counting as you go. Note that merely keeping a counter inside the iterator won't work, because you can remove objects from the list while you're iterating. Such heavy functionalities with little gain are avoided in C++. I don't know about Java (and I don't know why you keep bringing it up either).

Answer (score 0):

> why the iterator itself could not printed by doing the following?

Because, it is not defined to a value internally.

> Is there any other way to do this?

Basically, the compiler does not facilitate it by default, you may try to edit the compiler code! But it is too terrific you know!

> If not, why?

Because it has no well-defined way to express it.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that, you just want to know the position where the iterator points.
If so you can use `std::distance(numbers.begin(), it)`

Answer (score -4):

You can't print the iterator because it is not defined to have a value. But you can perform arithematic operations on them and that helps you to print the value (of the iterator).

Comment: This is exactly the first sentence of the most upvoted answer